# Getting a count for non null values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've looked everywhere on how to do this and it seems like an awful long approach to output 1 number.

This is the layout of my database:

```
UserId         Info1    Info2    Info3   Info4   Info5   Info6   Info7
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

user1      |   xyz   |         | abc   |  xyz  |       | abc   | 
user2      |         |  abc    |       |  def  |  ghi  | wxy   | jkl

What i want to do is return a number for example: 

User1 has completed 4 Tasks 
User2 has completed 5 Tasks
```

There are 95 columns in this row so as you can understand it would be a real pain to count each one individually. However i only want to count the ones that are not empty and return a number.

```
<?
$sql="SELECT * FROM builder WHERE userid = '".$userid."' IS NOT NULL";
$query=mysql_query($sql);    
$num=mysql_num_fields($query);
echo $num;?>
```

This outputs how many rows there are in total regardless of whether they are empty or not so the number is always the same which isn't what I want.

Any suggestions?

Comment: just use a while loop, inside it, loop all rows and check if its not empty, increase counter

Comment: any hint on a code for that Ghost?

Comment: maybe i'm missing something. Where was the actual mysql_query part in that code. When i put it into the site it just broke the layout lol.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the values in MySQL using this construct:

```
select ((info1 is not null) +
        (info2 is not null) +
        (info3 is not null) +
        (info4 is not null) +
        (info5 is not null) +
        (info6 is not null) +
        (info7 is not null)
       ) as NumNotNull
```

MySQL treats boolean expressions as integers, in a numeric context.  TRUE is "1", so you can just add them up to get the total that match.

Comment: so this means i would need to add all 95 columns to this yes?

Comment: @jay32mcr . . . Yes.  You can use `information_schema.columns` to get the columns.  If you are doing this manually, you can generate the code easily in a spreadsheet.  In an application, you can write php code to do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. In the end I did a join table with not null to resolve :)

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for the partial answer here (i.e. I haven't written out the proposed stored procedure) but perhaps this will be a start for you. My approach will take some time to write but will be particularly useful if new tasks are sometimes added as new columns in your builder table.

The approach is as follows: create a stored procedure that pivots your data. You then query off the result set generated by that procedure so that you query off a data set that looks like the following:

```
userID  task   Complete
------  ----   --------
user1   Info1  True
user1   Info2  False
user1   Info3  True
user1   Info4  True
user1   Info5  False
user1   Info6  True
user1   Info7  False
user2   Info1  False
user2   Info2  True
user2   Info3  False
user2   Info4  True
user2   Info5  True
user2   Info6  True
user2   Info7  True
```

I don't believe MySQL has a pivot command but you can imitate one by writing a stored procedure that dynamically generates an SQL statement as it reads off the built in INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS Table.

The dynamic SQL would look something like:

```
SELECT userID, 'Info1' AS Task, info1 IS NOT NULL FROM builder
UNION
SELECT userID, 'Info2' AS Task, info2 IS NOT NULL FROM builder
UNION
...
```

You'd have to play with this a while but I think it will give you a result that could be more useful.  BTW, if it's possible to redesign the builder table, a design that looks like what this stored procedure returns might be easier to work with.